# Why does String.replace with character classes convert German umlauts to Binaries?

Tags: elixir

(Apologies if my terminology regarding Binaries is off - I'm still getting started with Elixir)

While solving one of the [Exercism questions for Elixir](http://exercism.io), I noticed that `String.replace` as well as `Regex.replace` apparently convert German Umlauts to Binaries when using the `[:alnum:]` character class:

```
iex(1)> String.replace("ö", ~r/[[:alnum:]]/, "_")
<<95, 182>>
iex(2)> String.replace("ö", ~r/[^[:alnum:]]/, "_")
<<195, 95>>
iex(3)> String.replace("ö", ~r/[_]/, " ")
"ö"
```

Is this behaviour caused by my usage of the `[:alnum:]` character class? (what really baffles me is that both the first and the second version return a Binary)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass the `u` modifier to the Regex so that `[:alnum:]` and other such patterns match on Unicode strings.

```
iex(1)> String.replace("ö", ~r/[[:alnum:]]/u, "_")
"_"
iex(2)> String.replace("ö", ~r/[^[:alnum:]]/u, "_")
"ö"
```

From `h Regex`:

> Modifiers
>
> The modifiers available when creating a Regex are:
>
> - unicode (u) - enables unicode specific patterns like p and change
>     modifiers like w, W, s and friends to also match on unicode. It expects
>     valid unicode strings to be given on match
>
>   ...